# No module named '_gdbm'

Tags: python, installation

I don't know much about python and I need help to install a python software.

I am using linux mint 12.8.
Since I have tried many things I think I have several versions of python installed (3.5 and 3.7 I think...).

When I run `setup.py install` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/home/zach/10_Soft/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/dbm/gnu.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdbm'
```

I tried to install  `python3.5-gdbm` (which appears to be up to date) and `python3.7-gdbm` (which is not found).

They both seem to be virtual packages of the same package python3-gdbm. I don't really know what to do with this information however...

Do you know what I should do?

Comment: what is the output of `which python3`

Comment: `/home/zach/10_Soft/anaconda3/bin/python3`

Comment: Deactivate anaconda virtual environment first. Run `conda deactivate` and then try again. You are doing right.

Comment: Now it returns `/usr/bin/python3`.
`setup.py install` still returns the same error

Comment: No install `python3-gdbm` first as you mentioned in the question.
`sudo apt-get install python3-gdbm`

Comment: I get: `python3-gdbm is already at the most recent version (3.5.1-1).`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220223/discussion-between-suleman-elahi-and-zach).

Comment: If you would have continued it here, I might not have to search for python3.6-gdbm elsewhere....

Comment: I am afraid you would, we did not solve it unfortunately. It worked with a fresh install.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue using this command:

```bash
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Comment: I guess for virtual environment users, you have to choose the path accordingly